# Better way to bind event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a page where I have many controls and then I have a div element and have 10 asp buttons in that div element.

I want to bind mousehover event to only those buttons which are inside the div element.

Currently i m doing it like:

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#MangoPager_btn1").hover(mousehoverfunction);
            $("#MangoPager_btn2").hover(mousehoverfunction);
            $("#MangoPager_btn3").hover(mousehoverfunction);
            $("#MangoPager_btn4").hover(mousehoverfunction);
            $("#MangoPager_btn5").hover(mousehoverfunction);
            $("#MangoPager_btn6").hover(mousehoverfunction);
            $("#MangoPager_btn7").hover(mousehoverfunction);
            $("#MangoPager_btn8").hover(mousehoverfunction);
            $("#MangoPager_btn9").hover(mousehoverfunction);
            $("#MangoPager_btn10").hover(mousehoverfunction);
        }); 
</script>
```

Is there any way in jquery so that i can declare a list of button ids something like `[MangoPager_btn10,MangoPager_btn2,MangoPager_btn3]` so that i don't have to do that for every single button id.

I tried with `input` type but then it's applying the function for all input type objects not for buttons which are in the `div` elemet.

Any other bettrer way to do it in jquery ....
I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $("[id^='MangoPager_btn']").hover(mousehoverfunction);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#DivElementId input').hover(mousehoverfunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply give a class to the desired inputs:

```
$(".mouse-over").hover(mousehoverfunction);
```

or if you just have a few ids:

```
$("#MangoPager_btn1, #MangoPager_btn2, #MangoPager_btn3").hover(mousehoverfunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#MangoPager button").hover(mousehoverfunction);

Bind the function to the parent div and then all the buttons like this.  Assuming MagoPager is the id of the parent div.

or

$("#MangoPager input[type=]").hover(mousehoverfunction);

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$(".containerclass input[type=submit]").hover(mousehoverfunction);
```

this will bind the function to all buttons inside a container wit (css)class="containerclass"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using delegate: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ because it will attach a handler to one or more events for all elements

Answer (score 0):

In this cases I use filters http://api.jquery.com/filter/ with regexp

```
$("input").filter(function()
{
return /MangoPager_btn/.test(this.id)
}).hover(mousehoverfunction);
```